# Trying to generate ASV table from phyloseq

Tags: r, phyloseq

I recognize most people have the opposite problem. But I'm trying to create an ASV table, with column names as "identified OTUs" (aka the column name is drawn from the taxonomy information from `GlobalPatterns@tax.table`, rather than just being the assigned OTU code that's encoded in `GlobalPatterns@otu.table`), and row names as sample name.

I also want to append the metadata to the end of the ASV table, to allow for analysis based on said metadata.

I managed to generate a table *without* the taxonomic information with this code, using GlobalPatterns for reproducibility:

```
data(GlobalPatterns)
asv.matrix <- as.matrix(GlobalPatterns@otu_table@.Data)
asv <- data.frame(t(asv.matrix))                                   #transposing to make sample name the row name
meta.df <- as.data.frame(GlobalPatterns@sam_data)
asv.full <- data.frame(asv,meta.df)
write.csv(asv.full, file = "full_asv.csv",quote = FALSE,sep = ",")
```

However, I can't figure out how to force taxonomy information into the column names, which makes the ASV table functionally useless for analysis.

EDIT:
My preferred format is (abbreviated with faked metadata appended) as below. Tried to make a table, failed, have a fake code chunk.

```
Sample-ID / Species1 / Species2 / ...etc... / Metadata1 / Metadata2 /...etc... /
--------- / -------- / -------- / --------- / --------- / --------- /--------- /
Sample1   / 1        / 5        / ...etc... / lake      / summer    /...etc... /
Sample2   / 4        / 0        / ...etc... / bog       / spring    /...etc... /
```

Comment: Decided to just pull taxonomy data separately with `as.data.frame(GlobalPatterns@tax.table)` and let my advisor figure out how to connect the two. Dealing with my taxonomy data not all being "resolved" to the same level was getting messy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `phyloseq::psmelt` function, which combines the `otu_table`, `tax_table` and `sample_data` tables into a single, long format table that is suitable for analysis.

One way of dealing with unresolved taxonomy is to assign the highest known taxonomy to any unresolved level. You can use the `name_na_taxa` function from the [`fantaxtic`](https://github.com/gmteunisse/fantaxtic) package for this, prior to using `psmelt`.

**EDIT**

After seeing your updated post, I understand a bit better what you want. You can take the output from `psmelt` and pivot this into a semi-wide format; see the code chunk below.

```r
require("phyloseq")
require("fantaxtic")
require("tidyverse")

# Load data
data(GlobalPatterns)

# Generate (unique) species names using fantaxtic
ps <- name_na_taxa(GlobalPatterns)
ps <- label_duplicate_taxa(ps, tax_level = "Species", asv_as_id = T)

# Convert to long data format
ps_long <- psmelt(ps)

# Convert to semi-wide data format where each column has a taxon name
# and contains the abundance in each sample
meta_vars <- sample_variables(ps)
ps_wide <- ps_long %>%
  select(all_of(meta_vars), Species, Abundance) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Species,
              values_from = Abundance)

# Inspect the final table
head(ps_wide)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 19,223
#>   X.SampleID Primer  Final_Barcode Barcode_truncate~ Barcode_full_le~ SampleType
#>   <fct>      <fct>   <fct>         <fct>             <fct>            <fct>     
#> 1 AQC4cm     ILBC_17 ACAGCT        AGCTGT            CAAGCTAGCTG      Freshwate~
#> 2 LMEpi24M   ILBC_13 ACACTG        CAGTGT            CATGAACAGTG      Freshwater
#> 3 AQC7cm     ILBC_18 ACAGTG        CACTGT            ATGAAGCACTG      Freshwate~
#> 4 AQC1cm     ILBC_16 ACAGCA        TGCTGT            GACCACTGCTG      Freshwate~
#> 5 M31Tong    ILBC_10 ACACGA        TCGTGT            TGTGGCTCGTG      Tongue    
#> 6 M11Fcsw    ILBC_05 AAGCTG        CAGCTT            CGACTGCAGCT      Feces     
#> # ... with 19,217 more variables: Description <fct>,
#> #   `Unknown Stramenopiles (Order) 549656` <dbl>,
#> #   `Unknown Dolichospermum (Genus) 279599` <dbl>,
#> #   `Unknown Neisseria (Genus) 360229` <dbl>,
#> #   `Unknown Bacteroides (Genus) 331820` <dbl>,
#> #   `Haemophilusparainfluenzae 94166` <dbl>,
#> #   `Unknown ACK-M1 (Family) 329744` <dbl>, ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that this will potentially lead to a table with thousands of columns (about 20k in the case of `GlobalPatterns`), which might be hard to work with.

Comment: Actually, no, unfortunately. That method gets me an Excel sheet that's an ungodly 14 million rows and refuses to both email and open on a normal computer, and additionally isn't my advisor's preferred format. I'll edit the above with the preferred table format; not my brightest moment to forget to include.

Comment: Noted on the `name_na_taxa` function, though. Thanks for that tip.

Comment: Thanks for the updated table format. I've updated my post.